# Using command substituition in Makefiles

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, sh

In the Linux sh/bash shell, I can get Linux user ID with `UID_CODE=$(id -u):$(id -g)`. It usually gives `UID_CODE=1000:1000`

However, I'm writing a Makefile, similar to this:

```
run:
UID_CODE=$(id -u):$(id -g) ./a.out
```

The Makefile gives `UID_CODE=:` which is just the `:`

I did some digging and found I need to use `$$`, but `$$(id -u):$$(id -g)` gives me `UID_CODE=$(id -u):$(id -g)`

How do I get the same result as in the shell?

Comment: to clarify, is `UID_CODE` being set _inside_ the makefile, or it is being set outside the makefile and _used_ inside the makefile? (It sounds like you want to _set_ the variable in the makefile so that it's value can be passed to an executable, but just checking. See possible answer posted below...)

Comment: @michael I think I'm confusing Makefile variables and shell variables. I want to set `UID_CODE` as shell variable to run a command like `./a.out`. But your answer might work. Let me try it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will definitely work and is probably the best way to do this unless you need it to be done in lots and lots of rules:

```
run:
    UID_CODE=$$(id -u):$$(id -g) ./a.out
```

There's not really a good reason to use GNU make-specific features like the `shell` function here.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say: *gives me `UID_CODE=$(id -u):$(id -g)`*  Do you mean, that's what make prints out?  Yes, that's fine.  make is printing out the shell command that it will run, just as you would type it into your shell prompt.

When the shell runs that command it will expand the `$(id -u)` and replace it with the right UID.  For example you can test this:

```
run:
    UID_CODE=$$(id -u):$$(id -g) env | grep UID_CODE
```

Running make here will print the following:

```
UID_CODE=$(id -u):$(id -g) env | grep UID_CODE
UID_CODE=1000:1000
```

(or whatever your UID/GID values are).  The first line is make showing you the command it will run, and the second line is the output of the command showing that `UID_CODE` is set as you expect.

Comment: Yes, it printed out like that. I didn't know it still runs. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample makefile setting a variable and passing it via the environment to an external program in a rule (you can use `${...}` or `$(...)`):

```
$ cat Makefile.mk
FOO := "foo: $(shell id -g):$(shell id -u)"

tst:
    echo "testing: $(FOO)"
    FOO=${FOO} ./a.out
```

This is using the GNU makefile feature of `$(shell ...)`, but you're probably using GNU make so that shouldn't be a problem.